# Spring Cache property extraction

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I have two methods for which i have use @Cacheable annotation.

```
@Cacheable(value = "product", key = "#id")
public Product getProduct(String id) {
    Product product = productRepository.getProductById(id)
    return product;
}
```

and the second method is,

```
@Cacheable(value = "product", key="#id")
public Integer getProductType(String id) {
     return getProduct(id).getProductType();
}
```

The second method does not work. How can i extract only a property from the "product" cache? In this case, already product for that specific id is cached. i just need only the property from the cache. I am using Hazelcast as Cache provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the cache between two methods, I think you should do the following:

```
@Resource
private Service self;

@Cacheable(value = "product", key = "#id")
public Product getProduct(String id) {
    Product product = productRepository.getProductById(id)
    return product;
}

public Integer getProductType(String id) {
     return self.getProduct(id).getProductType();
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/leszko/caching-patterns/blob/extract-cache-value/src/main/java/com/leszko/cachingpatterns/pattern1plus/BookService.java#L18) is the complete working example that works.